# Flatten a List<Tuple<string,List<Object>>>

Tags: c#, linq

i have the following property:

```
List<Tuple<string,List<Object>>> GroupedItems
```

I need a List of all Objects.

Currently I am using a very pragmatic approach with a loop:

```
          List<Object> flatList = new List<Object>();
          foreach (var y in container.GroupedItems)
          {
            foreach(var z in y.Item2)
            {
            flatList.Add(z);
            }
          }
```

I am sure this operation can be done in a more comfortable way by using LINQ, unfortunately I do not have much experience with this.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What are `container` and `Item2`? Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You don't need to know what is 'container' it is good abstraction. 'Item2' - is obviously some Object cause it's added to such list.

Comment: @ChrisPickford `Item2` is the name of the second property in a `Tuple<T1, T2>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany):

```
List<Object> flatList = GroupedItems.SelectMany(item => item.Item2).ToList();
```

`SelectMany` projects all items in an enumeration to another enumeration. In your case it projects each tuple to the list of objects in that tuple (`Item2`).

Comment: Perfect, that is exactly what I was looking for, thx!!